# UnityFramework in Capacitor Ionic Project

Tags: ios, cordova, unity-game-engine, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to embed Unity inside a Capacitor Ionic Project.
I have created a [Cordova Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-unityar) which works fine on both Android and iOS(Cordova projects).

I am trying to use the same plugin in Capacitor Ionic project. Got it working in Android.
But in iOS the plugin source code goes to Pod project(Attaching screenshot). I added the UnityProject to the ionic capacitor project similar to how its done in [Cordova](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-unityar).

How can I include this header `#include <UnityFramework/UnityFramework.h>` inside the Pod Project?
When added it throws header not found error. Is there a way to communicate from Pod project to MainApp project. Can anybody help?

Thanks
Alan

[image]